# Tab bar method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I added this tab bar in view controller 1 and it works perfectly, the only issue is I want it to do the following function `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, but in view controller2 when the tab bar button is touched. What would be the best course of action?

```
UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
homeNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[DSTabBarItem alloc] initWithFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home"] 
                                                            finishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home1"]
                                                                                 iconSize:CGSizeMake(76, 59)
                                                                                tag:0];
[tabBarViewControllers addObject:homeNavigationController];
```

Comment: what's your need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you added tabbarcontroller programmatically . And In that class add the following method.
Then you navigation controller will changed to root view. And you can place your own between the if to your requirement.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([self.tabBarController.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [(UINavigationController*)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DetailSettingsViewController *settings = [[DetailSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailSettingsViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:settings animated:YES];
```